# Showing display time calculated fields in alfresco 4.2c share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

For a custom model type I need to show some display time calculated fields on the share interface. Is there any way of showing information in share without linking it to a field in the backing model?

I have tried creating a field with both empty and filled in id in the field-visibility/appearance share configuration but both seem to be ignored on render time.
Or is the only way of doing it adding a custom template to another field/form/set just to be able to add the extra field I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom template is the approach I've used in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add custom template, like Jeff said - but you could go another route. I'm not sure, but from your question you are trying to do some calculation and then show it.

If that's the case, you can do the following:

1. Extend the metadata component, specifically just make it calculate
   the extra data and put that into the model, for your custom content
   type.
2. Then you also extend the client-side javascript and make it
   show this extra info by creating markup.

Would that work for you?

Comment: One thing I would like to avoid is storing the calculated value into the model. This to prevent that if the calculation changes in the future that I don't have to update all existing documents.

Comment: Well that's what I suggested. Ie - you want to show how much time between cm:modified and cm:created has passed. If both fields are on the share form, you can just add a bit of functionality in the client-side javascript: it takes the two dates, calculates the difference, then adds a node and displays the result. Or do that in the controller script for the metadata display. This way you don't have a new template component, but you have to edit the metadata view component. Depends on your use case, I guess. Jeff's way is probably better, but I just wanted to mention another option.